# How to introduce changes in pdm with sql script via PowerDesigner

Tags: sql, sybase, reverse-engineering, sql-scripts, powerdesigner

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Hi, all!
I have a database model xxx.pdm and a sql script I want to apply to the db (so that generated xxx_db.sql, xxx_triggers.sql, etc will contain the changes - the files are used in whole application building process to generate yyy.db file).

I've tried to:

1. open the pdm file with PowerDesigner 16.5
2. go to Database->Update Model from Database...
3. select "using script files" and specified a sql file (with some create index, alter table statements). pressed ok
4. PowerDesigner showed progress dialog and a dialog merge models with yellow locks near some of the entities.
5. I try to generate database: Database->Generate database... in the dialog xxx_db.sql is selected.

the result - generation aborted due to errors detected during the verification of the model.

```
Category    Check           Object                      Location
Reference   Incomplete join Reference 'FK_table1_col1'  <Model>
Reference   Incomplete join Reference 'FK_table2_col2'  <Model>
```

at the same time the sql script is well executed via Sybase Interactive (cmd line).

Is my approach correct?
Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Your process seems reasonable. Are these check errors present in your initial model, or introduced by the reverse of the SQL script? "incomplete join", I guess it's when a join of the reference, between a primary key column and a foreign key column is missing one of these (probably the FK column). It may be a problem with the script reverse, which could be fixed by changing sql script a little, or you could contact the technical support.

Comment: I've already discovered that PD may not "understand" the script well. The script contains a few statements for creation of FK's between previously existing columns and a new one's (created previously in the same script). Ant PD does not manage to link old col's to new one's. Fortunately there is not too many of them, so I've correct it manually.